# Magento 2 | How to print all custom attributes of order?

Tags: magento2, orders, custom-attributes

can you tell me how I can print all custom attributes an order has programatically?

Thanks!

Comment: Load the order and print $order->getData() will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code if you want to use **objectManager**:

```
$orderId = 1;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($order->getData());
echo '</pre>';
```

If you have order increment id then use below code:

```
$incrementId = '10000001';
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($order->getData());
echo '</pre>';
```

And if you are using any module and class then inject **\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface** to your construct function:

```
protected $order;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order,
    ......
) {
    $this->order = $order;

}
```

And load order in your public function like below:

```
public function getOrderByIncrementId($incrementId){
    return $this->order->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);
}

public function getOrderByEntityId($orderId){
    return $this->order->load($orderId);
}
```